# how to unbind click while a video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, bind, unbind

I have a set of buttons in an array, and I want it so that when you click one, and a video that it's linked to starts to play, it unbinds the `click` to the buttons (ideally for the one you just clicked only, but I can't even get it to work for the `li`). I have it as

```
$("#myVid").bind("playing", function() {
  //some stuff that happens
  $("li", ".thumbs").unbind('playVideo()')
        });
```

but it's not working... what am I doing wrong here? (  `playVideo()` is an already defined function)

Just to be more specific: 
the problem is that it's supposed to `unbind` only once the video is playing, hence the `.bind("playing", function()...`. I can get it deactivate the list, but its before it should...

Comment: $("li", ".thumbs").unbind(playVideo) try referencing the function not a string that contains the code to evaluate.

Comment: How sure are you that the "playing" handler is executing at all? (What happens if you put an alert right before the line with `.unbind()`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn I know it's executing because other functions that are bound to (a few fades for other divs work just fine)

Comment: if you replace the unbind with a remove call do the elements you expect disappear

Comment: _"I can get it deactivate the list, but its before it should"_ - are you saying the code `$("li",".thumbs").unbind("click");` will successfully unbind the click handlers from the li elements if you put it somewhere other than inside the "playing" event handler?

Comment: @nnnnnn no, I meant that it will unbind, but immediatly, which doesn't allow the videos to play. It should unbind once they've started playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the event like so:

```
$("li", ".thumbs").bind("click", playVideo);
```

the opposite action would be to do this:

```
$("li", ".thumbs").unbind("click", playVideo);
```

The same function used to bind the click event must be used to remove the same event.

```
function click() {
    $("#myVid").bind("loadeddata", function() {
    $("#bigPic").addClass("move");
    $("#MyT").fadeOut(750);
            });
    playVideo( $(this).index() );
}

$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', click);

$("#myVid").bind("playing", function() {
    $('li', '.thumbs').unbind('touchend click', click);
});
```

Comment: I have the `playVideo` in the `bind`, as you said it needed to be, but under `("click", function() {...}`. Does that not work?

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2 - that means you haven't actually bound `playVideo` at all, you've bound an anonymous function that just happens to call `playVideo()`. You can't unbind an anonymous function specifically, but you can unbind all handlers on an element with `.unbind("click")` (as per my answer). Perhaps you could update your question to show the original bind statement?

Comment: if you try and unbind an event with a different handler this will result in nothing happening. The original bind statement would help

Comment: The bind statement that sets up the click event on the $("li", ".thumbs")

Comment: Yeah! I realized that after you mentioned it, and I got it, so I can move onto the next part! Thank you sooooo much!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the [`.unbind()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)? You have to pass the name of the event you are unbinding (though there is an overload that lets you pass an event object). Try:

```
$("li", ".thumbs").unbind('click');
```

You can optionally pass a reference to the specific handler to unbind:

```
$("li", ".thumbs").unbind('click',playVideo);
```

The latter is necessary if you're binding multiple handlers and just want to unbind a specific one.

(And if you're using the jQuery version 1.7 or later I'd suggest using the [`.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead.)

Comment: the problem is that it's supposed to go when the video is playing, hence the `.bind("playing", function()...`. I can get it deactivate the list, but its immediate....

Comment: I agree with the on off methods suggested. It adds to the readability of the code and is jquerys suggested method